# Android: timestamp for SensorEventListener

Tags: android, android-sensors

when i shake the device iam triggering an intent  using sensorevenetlistner
the problem is only on little shake the intent is firing, but i want it to fire only
when i shake the device 3 times or certain number of shakes

```
private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
        / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
    {
      if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
        return;
      }
      lastUpdate = actualTime;
      //Toast.makeText(this, "Device was shuffed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         // .show();


      Intent myIntent = new Intent(SensorTestActivity.this, passwordActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
  }
};
```

below is my complete code

http://pastebin.com/1WtHYH6z

i am struck..any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a field

```
int _shaken;
```

in your SensorEvent:
 (I don't know the correct functionName but I guess you do..)

```
OnEvent(){
shaken++;
if(_shaken>=3){
doAction();
_shaken = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

taking into account Goot's answer, your program should look something like :

```
int count = 0;
private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
    mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
    float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
    mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

    //adjust the mAccel > certain_value (adjust this to change the sensitivity of the       
        //shake) 
    if(mAccel > 5) {
    Toast.makeText(SensorTestActivity.this, "Device is shaking!",      
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        count++;
        if(count >= 3) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(SensorTestActivity.this,    
                passwordActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            count = 0; //if you want to reset the counter after performing the action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cokeby..hi with the above code the app is starting with toast msg and login page and with minimum shake the login page is reappearing...

Comment: then you would need to increase the mAccel from 5 to a value larger so it will be less sensitive to the slight shaking movement.
Do you also mean that once the login page is appearing with lesser than 3 shakes?

Comment: yeah if i am taking the device in my hand, for tht movement the login is comming :(

Comment: hmm. So have you tried increasing the value to more than 5 yet?

Comment: i increased it to 8, but when the app starts i am getting the login screen getting triggered along with the main screen :(